# Mutate multiple new columns based on references to themselves

Tags: r

A data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  date = seq(ymd('2021-01-01'), ymd('2021-01-31'), by = 1),
  ims_x = rnorm(31, mean = 0),
  ims_y = rnorm(31, mean = 1),
  ims_z = rnorm(31, mean = 2),
  blah = 1:31
)
```

I'd like to mutate 3 new fields (not overwrite), 'ims_x_lagged', 'ims_y_lagged' and 'ims_z_lagged' where each new field corresponds to the original but lagged by one day/row. The names of the new fields would just have '_lagged' appended onto the name of the original and the value would change to be that of it's original in the preceding row.

I could do this manually for each field, but that would be a lot of typing and my real data has many more than 3 fields that need to be lagged.

Something kind of like this, if it's possible to tell what I'm trying to do:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(contains('ims_')) := lag(vars(contains('ims_')))) # but append '_lagged' to the name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new version of `dplyr`, `_at` or `_all` are getting deprecated and in its place, can use the more flexible `across`.  If we don't specify the `.names`, it will replace the modified column values with the same column name.  By specifying the `.names`, the `{.col}` - returns the original column name and can add either prefix or suffix as a string.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
     mutate(across(starts_with('ims'), lag, .names = "{.col}_lagged"))
```